# pro-actively or proactively

Tags: writing-style

When I write `proactively` in my WinShell Latex editor, it underline it as a spelling error. My question is: is writing `proactively` correct?
When shall I use `pro-actively` (with hyphen), and when I should not?

Comment: The editor is wrong. The hyphenated version is rare at best. `Proactively` is the right choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Proactive', and by extension `proactively`, are correct. `Pro-active` and `pro-actively` were the norm in the past, using `pro` as a prefix to `active`. Whilst they are still correct to use today, over time, `proactive` and `proactively` became accepted into culture and into English dictionaries, and they are now the norm (and recommended to use).

`Pr-oactively` was never correct and is a spelling error